# Unable to break out of While loop

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

I would like to break out of a loop when it gets to a blank line in a file. The issue is that my regexp's used to condition my data create a line with characters so I need something from the beginning to check if a line is empty or not so I can break out. What am I missing?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#NOTES: chmod this script with chmod 755 to run as regular local user

#This line allows for passing in a source file as an argument to the script (i.e: ./script.sh source_file.txt)
input_file="$1"

#This creates the folder structure used to mount the SMB Share and copy the assets over to the local machines
SOURCE_FILES_ROOT_DIR="${HOME}/operations/source" 
DESTINATION_FILES_ROOT_DIR="${HOME}/operations/copied_files"

#This creates the fileshare mount point and place to copy files over to on the local machine.
 echo "Creating initial folders..."
 mkdir -p "${SOURCE_FILES_ROOT_DIR}"
 mkdir -p "${DESTINATION_FILES_ROOT_DIR}"
 echo "Folders Created! Destination files will be copied to ${DESTINATION_FILES_ROOT_DIR}/SHARE_NAME"


while read -r line; 
  do  
    if [ -n "$line" ]; then 
        continue
    fi      
    line=${line/\\\\///}
    line=${line//\\//}
    line=${line%%\"*\"}
    SERVER_NAME=$(echo "$line" | cut -d / -f 4);
    SHARE_NAME=$(echo "$line" | cut -d / -f 5);
    ASSET_LOC=$(echo "$line" | cut -d / -f 6-);
    SMB_MOUNT_PATH="//$(whoami)@${SERVER_NAME}/${SHARE_NAME}";

     if df -h | grep -q "${SMB_MOUNT_PATH}"; then
       echo "${SHARE_NAME} is already mounted. Copying files..."
     else
       echo "Mounting it"
       mount_smbfs "${SMB_MOUNT_PATH}" "${SOURCE_FILES_ROOT_DIR}"
      fi
   cp -a ${SOURCE_FILES_ROOT_DIR}/${ASSET_LOC} ${DESTINATION_FILES_ROOT_DIR}

  done < $input_file

# cleanup
 hdiutil unmount ${SOURCE_FILES_ROOT_DIR}

exit 0
```

Expected result was for the script to realize when it gets to a blank line and then stops. The script works works when i remove the

```sh
if [ -n "$line" ]; then 
    continue
fi
```

The script runs and pulls assets but just keeps on going and never breaks out. When I do it as is now I get :

> Creating initial folders...
>   Folders Created! Destination files will be copied to /Users/baguiar/operations/copied_files
>   Mounting it
>   mount_smbfs: server connection failed: No route to host
>   hdiutil: unmount: "/Users/baguiar/operations/source" failed to unmount due to error 16.
>   hdiutil: unmount failed - Resource busy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat test.txt
```

> This is some file
>   There are lines in it
>
> And empty lines
>
> etc

```
while read -r line; do
  if [[ -n "$line" ]]; then
    continue
  fi
  echo "$line"
done < "test.txt"
```

will print out

> 

That's because [`-n` matches strings that are not null, i.e., non-empty](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html).

It sounds like you have a misunderstanding of what `continue` means. It does not mean "continue on in this step of the loop", it means "continue to the *next* step of the loop", i.e., go to the top of the `while` loop and run it starting with the next line in the file.

Right now, your script says "go line by line, and if the line is not empty, skip the rest of the processing". I think your goal is actually "go line by line, and if the line is empty, skip the rest of the processing". This would be achieved by `if [[ -z "$line" ]]; then continue; fi`

**TL;DR** You are skipping all the non-empty lines. Use [`-z` to check if your variable is empty](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) instead of `-n`.

Comment: Thank you @jeremysprofile but I tried with -z and it will say "that share is already mounted but wont copy data and then fails to unmount because it never got mounted.

Comment: That is a separate problem, and you probably should open a separate question for it. It seems like you don't fully understand this code; maybe you should ask the person you got it from about it?

Comment: I'm a noob..but I wrote all that code. Turns out the issue was related to network/system hiccup. But it's working now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry for doubting you. I'm glad you got it working!